# Codeception install problem - vendor/bin/codecept vendor not recognised as internal... windows10

Tags: php, composer-php, codeception

When I download codeception with composer and run vendor/bin/codecept from project directory, it says vendor not recognized as internal or external program.

There is a folder inside vendor codeception/codeception/codecept bootstrap and it works if I run it from in there but when creating a class test and running the tests I get weird results like isAngularTest....?? 
I have tried quite a few different commands but cant get it to work they way the codeception website indicates or how my lecture says it should. I am using windows 10.

Comment: I also hat problems with the composer version of codeception. Did you try the phar file? That worked for me using Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `vendor\bin\codecept.bat` and not `vendor\bin\codecept` - the latter one is a Bash script, it won't start in Windows command line.

I am not sure why you tagged this question with `PhpStorm`, so I'll put [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-codeception-framework.html) here just in case.